# create my own max and explicit package name requires in perl

Tags: perl, package, global, symbols

I'm not use to coding in perl (it's the first time) but I have to work on a small part of code who someone send me, but I have this error which seem to be a common error for newbie :

`Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at globalAlgt.pl line 30.`

`Global symbol "$y" requires explicit package name at globalAlgt.pl line 30.`

On the line 30 I have this :

`my $max = ($x, $y)[$x < $y];`

which seem to be a function max created. I think it's because there is `use strict;` in the code.

Can you explain me this error ? 
Thank you !

Comment: show us the previous lines of code, $x and $y should be declared with "my"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you that there is no $x and $y declared before, is that the reason of the error ? And if it's the reason, how can I declare if I don't want to set only one value ?

Comment: yes, you need to declare those variables (because of `use strict;`). `my ($x, $y) = (10, 20);` for example

Comment: More exactly, the shorthand for `$x` is disabled when you `use strict`, which is a good thing to use. You can use `$main::x`, or you can declare a lexical variable with `my`, e.g. `my $x;` This needs to be before all the uses of `$x`, naturally.

Comment: That is a horrible way of writing `my $max = $x < $y ? $y : $x`. But it's probably better to `use List::Util 'max'` and then `my $max = max($x, $y)`

Answer (score 2):

That can be re-written as a function

```
my $max = sub { $_[ $_[0] < $_[1] ] };
```

which can then be invoked as

```
print $max->(3,5), "\n";
print $max->(5,3), "\n";
```

At least, that's what I understand by "define my own `max`" and "*function* `max`".

Or, you can just use [List::Util::max](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#max).